# Why is this erb code throwing "Undefined method 'match' for []:Array"?

Tags: regex, sinatra, erb

Hope someone can help me resolve this problem.

I have an instance variable holding some string values in a params. Here are the string values:

```
"The Hoboken Four" "Anita Baker" "No One Cares" "Giant" "Taking A Chance On Love" "[]" "["quiz"]" "quiz"
```

I would like to display only the values that match:
"The Hoboken Four" "Anita Baker" "No One Cares" "Giant" "Taking A Chance On Love"

Here is the code in my app.rb:

```
post '/:form_type' do
  @array = []
  @results = params
  @results.each do |key, value|
    if value.match(/\w[^["quiz"]]/)
      @array << value
    end
    @array
  end
    erb :results
end
```

Here is the code I have in my view:

```
<% @array.each do |item| %>
  <p><%= item %></p>
<% end %>
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Have you tried to escape `"["quiz"]"`?

Comment: @Sirl33tname : I just tried escaping "["quiz"]" as you suggested using this regex expression:
`<% @results.each do |key, value| %>
  <% if value.match(/\w[^\A"["quiz"]"\\]/) %>
    <% @array << value %>
    <% @array %>
    <% end %>
  <% @array.each do |item| %>
    <p><%= item %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>`

And I still get the same result. 

Is my code for escaping `"["quiz"]"`?

Comment: Can you show us what's in params (`warn params.inspect` will display it in the console) ?

Comment: @iain: when I run `results.erb` in console (after having changed code in results.erb to `(warn params.inspect)` I get error message: `syntax error, unexpected '<'
<%= (warn params.inspect) %>
 ^
results.erb:2: unterminated string meets end of file`

I have tried changing my syntax in different ways but still get some version of this error. I should also admit that I have never tried running an erb file in my terminal before so I don't know the correct way to issue the command. Can you please give me directions on how to do this?

Comment: My fault, put it in the route after the `post` line.

Comment: @iain: Thank you for getting back to me (and sorry it took this long to reply). I finally figured out a solution. Thank you for every much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, what I think happened is that OP was using `[]` in the parameters name, most likely to send all the values under a unique name. For instance if the HTML form looks like that:

```
<input type="text" name="title[]"/>
<input type="text" name="title[]"/>
```

and the user inputs `First` and `Second`, Sinatra is going to interpret the `[]` in the parameter name and aggregate the different values in a table:

```
{"title"=>["First", "Second"]}
```

So in OP's code, `value.match` was throwing because value was of type `Array` (as the error message states).